# ADObject has wrong timestamp

Tags: active-directory, timestamp

Some timestamp of ADObject(ADUser, ADComputer) is 2030-XX-YY. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: How did you collect that information?

Comment: [datetime]::FromFileTime((Get-ADUser -Properties LastLogonTimestamp).LastLogonTimestamp)

Comment: That's not valid code.